# Twitter Bootstrap 3: Click link in modal window, close it and smooth scroll to hash

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, smooth-scrolling

I'm using the jQuery One Page Navigation plugin [Git link](http://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav) and Twitter Bootstrap 3.3. Everything works fine except one thing: additional links in modal window doesn't work with smooth scroll effect.

I've found this solution for inline links:

```
function scrollNav() {            
    $('#program_scroll a, #closemodal a').click(function(evn){
        evn.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').scrollTo(this.hash, this.hash);        
    }); 
}
```

My jQuery skills are limited so I haven't found the solution for this issue.
Here is the live website: [website](http://tedxmru.com/)

The problem is happening in section called **News** - once the modal window is opened - three links in the end of text are displayed. 
I want that once those links are clicked the modal window closes and page is scrolled to hash'ed content

This is the code which closes the modal window:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
   $('.closemodal').click(function() {                                
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
   });                                        
</script>
```

The script is placed in `index.js` file and called by `function scrollNav() {`and `inline` JS placed in `index.html`:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (evn) {           
   evn.preventDefault();
   $('html,body').scrollTo(this.hash, this.hash);  
});
```

As I understand the `$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (evn) {` doesn't receive the hash of clicked link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
  $('.closemodal').click(function() {   
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');   
  $('html,body').scrollTo(this.hash, this.hash);
  });   
</script>
```

Very strange, firstly once I've tried this code - there was no any effect :/